# Find infimum and supremum of a set with a given boundary

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that the set

$$M=\bigg\{\frac{6}{(x-2)^3}:x≤0\bigg\}$$

is bounded and find infM and supM.

My attempt was "assume" when x is 0 and when x approaches infinity, that would give me:
$$supM=0$$
$$infM=-\frac{3}{4}$$

I would then prove that these are infact sup and inf of M by assuming there is a smaller upperbound then 0 and and bigger lower bound then -3/4, prove that that is not the case and then we are done.
I have not managed to do so, one of my biggest issues is that the denominator is negative, any suggestions? 
Or perhaps even a full solution?
Thanks beforehand

Comment: " one of my biggest issues is that the denominator is negative" that's actually a huge *help*.  That means 0 *is* an upper bound.  And as it is a limit it is a least upper bound. (Otherwise you have utterly no reason to assume the limits were any type of extrema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$y = \frac{6}{(x-2)^3} \implies \frac{6}{y}=(x-2)^3.$$
Since $(x-2)^3$ is a decreasing function of $x$ for $x \le 0$, $$-\infty<\frac{6}{y}=(x-2)^3 \le (0-2)^3=-8.$$ Also, $-\infty < \frac{6}{y} \le -8$ implies $y <0$. Therefore, $$\frac{6}{y} \le -8 \implies y \ge -\frac{6}{8}=-\frac{3}{4},$$ and $$\frac{6}{y}>-\infty \implies y<0.$$

Answer (score 0):

it is fact that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}M=0$$ and $$f(x)=\frac{6}{(x-2)^3}$$ is monotonously decreasing thus your infimum is given by $$-\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x \le 0$ then $x-2<0$ and $\frac 6 {(x-2)^3}<0$.  So $0$ is an upper bound.

You say you have shown the limit as $x $ goes to negative infinity is $0$.  I'll take your word for that.  But that means for any $d <0$ the is an $x$ where  $\frac 6 {(x-2)^3}>d$.  So $d$ is not an upper bound.

So $0$ is the least upper bound.

Now in $x \le 0$ then $(x-2)^3\le 8$ and $\frac 6 {(x-2)^3}\ge -\frac 34$.  So $-\frac 34$ is a lower bound.  As it is a lower bound that actually gets achieved, it must be the greatest lower bound (because anything greater can not be as low as it and thus can't be a lower bound).

In essence since the function is decreasing the extrema are the limits.  BUT  in general "assuming" the limits were the extrema *without* knowing the function was increasing/decreasing was completely unwarranted.